# cant retrieve json from api using okhttp

Tags: android, json

Hello there im trying to retrieve json from a simple api using okhttp but im failing to do so i need assistance. I can log the string with the json data well but i cant seem to place it in my android application. here is the code for the fetch. I dont know where the problem is but it is showing an error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText txtBookName;
    TextInputEditText txtVerse;
    Button btnSearch;
    OkHttpClient client;
    Request request;
    TextView txtJson;
    String bodyString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        txtBookName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBookName);
        txtVerse = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVerse);
        btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String chapter = txtBookName.getText().toString();
                String verse = txtVerse.getText().toString();
                //https://bible-api.com/john%204:15
                final MediaType JSON
                        = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                request = new Request.Builder().url("https://bible-api.com/"+chapter+verse).get().build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {


                    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        ResponseBody body = response.body();
                        bodyString = body.string();
                        MediaType contentType = body.contentType();
                        Log.d("Response", bodyString);
                        return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyString)).build();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure (@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {} // transmission failure callback
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                        final String string = response.body().string();
                        Log.i("cheese", "onResponse: "+string);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               try {
                                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                                    Snackbar.make(v,jsonData,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }});
                }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you seem to be building a badly formatted URL.

Change:

```
request = new Request.Builder().url("https://bible-api.com/"+chapter+verse).get().build();enter code here
```

to:

```
request = new Request.Builder().url("https://bible-api.com/%" + chapter + ":" + verse).get().build();
```